# Count observations by ID and Date without unique values

Tags: r, count, group

im working on a database which includes date variables and sistolic pressure measures. It looks like this:

| ID | DATE | SISTOLIC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-25 | 128 |
| 1 | 2021-11-26 | 125 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 |

The objective is to count registries for each ID and DATE. In the above example, the answer must be 3. I tried using `n_distinct()` from `dplyr` package but is not right because 128 are the same number, but measured in different dates (and i need to take that into account).
Here is the code im using

```
data <-data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n_sistolic= n_distinct(SISTOLIC),
         n_days_followup= n_distinct(DATE)) # Number of days during follow up
```

I except that my data looks like this:

| ID | DATE | SISTOLIC | n_sistolic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-25 | 128 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-11-26 | 125 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-11-27 | 128 | 3 |

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How would you like to see your output? could you put an example of the ideal output for this data? you can construct it manually and post it.

Comment: @RuamPimentel Thank you, i edited the post to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Does that solve your problem?

**library**

```r
library(dplyr)
```

**Data**

```r
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~DATE, ~SISTOLIC,
   1L, "2021-11-25",      128L,
   1L, "2021-11-26",      125L,
   1L, "2021-11-27",      128L
  )
```

**Solution**

```r
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n_sistolic= sum(!is.na(SISTOLIC)),
         n_days_followup= n_distinct(DATE))
```

**Output**

```r
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID DATE       SISTOLIC n_sistolic n_days_followup
#>   <int> <chr>         <int>      <int>           <int>
#> 1     1 2021-11-25      128          3               3
#> 2     1 2021-11-26      125          3               3
#> 3     1 2021-11-27      128          3               3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion. Using `sum(!is.na(SISTOLIC))` is not working because i have repeated measures that i dont want to count. I provided another example in the post. I need to count every different combination between id and date. If a person with the same id has the same date, i should count it just once. Using your code, the expected output is 6. It is my fault because i did not provide enough information.

Comment: If there is no missing, then your original code works. `data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n_sistolic = n_distinct(DATE))` this produces the same output you showed in your question.